# Create link to external URL on MVC3 asp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, external

I have the following code and I need to change the text "Check Availability" into a link that will open a url like https://website.com

How can I do that?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    if (ApplicationSetting.GetByNameBoolean("Web_AllowBackOrder", true, "") && orderLine.Product.TrackInventory)
                {
                    var inv = (Int32)(orderLine.Product.QtyOnHand - totalOrdered);
                    if (inv < 0)
                        line.Availability = "Check Availability";
                    else if (inv <= model.InventoryLowStockQuantity)
                        line.Availability = "Low Stock";
                    else
                        line.Availability = "Available";
                }
```

Comment: What is Availability defined as? And what does your View/HTML look like?

Comment: Hi Optimus,

public virtual string Availability { get; set; }

The view is just calling the function that the code belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup an HTML Helper, like so:

```
public static string SimpleLink(this HtmlHelper html, string url, string text)
{
    return String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", url, text);
}
```

In your view, use your HTML Helper:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <%= Html.SimpleLink(line.Url,line.Availability) %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This should point you into the right direction.

Comment: Hi Optimus and thank you for the response.
I am new to the mvc and didn't understand your suggestion.
The Helper I need to set it up in my controller where the code is?
Where do I put the external url (www.google.com) that I want to display? 

Forgive my ignorance and thank you.